# Get rid of "seen" messages at GMail

Tags: unix, email, gmail, fetchmail

The following is written by `fetchmail` in its log file:

```
fetchmail: 96 messages (96 seen) for my@email at pop.gmail.com (638442 octets).
```

From time to time this number of "seen" messages increases. It has nothing to do with the actual number of messages in my GMail inbox (which is much larger).

1. What does this number actually mean?
2. How do I reset it / get rid of these messages?

Comment: My guess is it means that of the X messages to be downloaded, Y have been read, are seen. What exactly do you want to get rid of, the emails or this message from the log?

Comment: @terdon: but why does GMail offer those Y messages for download, if they have been downloaded before? I'd like to get rid of the log messages, but first of all to understand what's going on.

Comment: I am guessing again, but "seen" would mean that you have read them in the HTML interface, you will then download all messages you don't have locally, not just the unread ones.